# I can't put today's date in a LocalDate variable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I try to fill an object with the name Reservation with an attribute of type LocalDate

```
private LocalDate dateReservation;
```

And I want to fill the Reservation class like this

```
ReservationDto reservationDto = new ReservationDto();
```

The class Reservation and ReservationDto have the same library for LocalDate

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
```

To load the reservation date I tried several ways as follows:

```
    log.info("Date : " + LocalDate.now());
    LocalDate str = LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 15);
    log.info("the date is " + str);
    
    reservationDto.setDateReservation(str);
    reservationDto.setDateReservation(LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 15));
    reservationDto.setDateReservation(LocalDate.now());
```

With the log the date is displayed but with setReservationDate the following message is displayed:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDate` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: fr.gopartner.locationvoiture.dto.ReservationDto["dateReservation"])
```

I use JDK 11. And i tried to add the dependences:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to change the dependencies, load the mapper object to serialize/unserialize my ReservationDto object and still shows me the same error above InvalidDefinitionException.
Please help me I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your Jackson ObjectMapper to add support for JDK 8 Date/time classes. The easiest way is like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Depending on the version of Jackson you're using, there are various other ways to do this, more info is on the [Jackson Java 8 modules](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/2.16/datetime) page.

Comment: But i use JDK 11not 8. how I can put this code with my code?

Comment: Should be the same. The date/time classes were first introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score -1):

You need to register the time module by adding the following code

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Comment: how I can put this code with my code? in the methode 

log.info("Date : " + LocalDate.now());
    LocalDate str = LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 15);
    log.info("the date is " + str);
    
    reservationDto.setDateReservation(str);
    reservationDto.setDateReservation(LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 15));
    reservationDto.setDateReservation(LocalDate.now());

Comment: these code lines should run before you use LocalDate class. you can try adding them to the start of your main function